# Password Reset Redirect

Tags: 7, users

I've been trying to redirect the password reset page to my custom login page by creating a small custom module; however it's not resolving properly.

Has anyone done this before with success?  The code that I'm trying to use is:

```
function m2f_password_reset_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#action'] == "/user/password"){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'user-pass';
  }
 }
/**
* Redirects user after password reset form is filled
*/
function m2f_password_redirect(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/20';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three possible issues that I can see:

- You are probably not prefixing the function with the right string.
  If the module/theme name is m2f_password, then `m2f_password_reset_form_alter()` is not recognized at implementation of `hook_form_alter()`.
- If you are trying to alter the form that is shown at user/password, you should not check `$form['#action']`; you should implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, and write a function called `m2f_password_form_user_pass_alter()`. (I assume the short name of the module/theme is m2f_password; if it is not correct, replace m2f_password with the short name of the module/theme.)
- `user-pass` is not a valid form submission callback name: PHP functions cannot contains hyphens. You are then defining `m2f_password_redirect()`, and that seems a form submission callback.
  The correct code is probably the following one.

  ```
  $form['#submit'][] = 'm2f_password_redirect';
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'user-pass';
```

The string that you add to the `$form['#submit']` array must be a the name of a valid, existing PHP function. It's likely you just need to change that line to:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'm2f_password_redirect';
```

Don't forget that PHP function names can't contain hyphens so `user-pass` would never be a valid name for a submit handler.

Comment: I understand, and have updated, but it's still not pulling through.  m2f_ is the theme name, correct?  I have the suspicion that there is something small that I'm overlooking.  Thanks for your input/advice!  For reference, I've been trying to follow this page: http://drupal.org/node/1458894